# Open eml file link in Outlook 2010 (and not browser)

Tags: javascript, html, outlook, eml

In my application, i have hyperlinks to .eml files. when i click on an .eml file link, the eml opens in the browser (IE).

What i want instead, is to open the .eml in Outlook 2010 directly (or the associated program) and not the browser.

Note that if double-click on an .eml file from my filesystem, the .eml opens in Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of your browser settings on how to handle the different file/mime types. Have a look there and link the .eml file ending to your Outlook 2010 installation. If you need more control about opening programs on the user's computer you'll need to use Flash or probably Silverlight. Just using HTML and Javascript does not let you control what software is handling the files you are linking to - this is for your own security. And still even with Flash you can't totally control on what software will handle your linked files - as far as I remember you can only set the mime type and that way steer the user's computer into the right direction.

Comment: i have 5000 users, i can't enjoy my time changing 5000 IE browsers, nor to Push the settings. Is there a way to enforce opening .eml files in Outlook 2010 using JavaScript?

Comment: No, it's not. What a computer does with a certain file type depends on the computer and CAN NOT be enforced by any HTML/JS page, I'm sorry. It this were possible, then spreading viruses over websites would be more than easy, and that is basically the reason why you can't do this.