# Creating .msg file[Email] in Java or Javascript?

Tags: java, email, hyperlink, outlook, jakarta-mail

Actually, I want to create a hyperlink on my webpage.On clicking that hyperlink, it should open with MS Outlook window for sending email, in which To,From and Subject field will be populated dynamically.

So far I tried using Java Mail API and successfully able to create .eml file.I created hyperlink with that .eml file on my web page.But It did not open with MS outlook,instead it showed in browser itself.So I thought might be with .msg file it will work.But i do not know how to create .msg file.

here is code to create .eml file :

```
public static void createMessage(String to, String from, String subject, String body, List<File> attachments) {
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(Session.getInstance(System.getProperties()));
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        // create the message part 
        MimeBodyPart content = new MimeBodyPart();
        // fill message
        content.setText(body);
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(content);
        // add attachments
        for(File file : attachments) {
            MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
            attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            attachment.setFileName(file.getName());
            multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
        }
        // integration
        message.setContent(multipart);
        // store file
        message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/mail.eml")));
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mailkit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mailkit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

So please let me know how can I create .msg file using Java or if you know any other way to accomplish my task then please let me know.

Comment: I am stuck at this problem.Please help.

Comment: For those looking at opening `.eml` file links in Outlook instead of the browser, [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553111/open-eml-file-link-in-outlook-2010-and-not-browser). Looks like it is client-dependent.

Comment: What about .msg file?

Comment: I was posting that comment and link to let others know that trying to get `.eml` files working is likely a lost cause, and should focus on another solution such as making `.msg` files. How to do that, I don't know off the top of my head.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869441/read-msg-file-with-java-mail-api-pls-suggest-me/14873139#14873139

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want a [mailto link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto)?  You don't get to control which mail client it opens in (after all, the user may not have Outlook), and there's some other functionality issues, but it sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: I am creating webpage on my company's intranet and here everybody has MS Outlook.Your solution work if somehow I force to open the link in MS Outlook only.Anyway Thank you for your answer.